# Proper usage of iterator for map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have this struct:

```
struct next
{
    string name;
    bool isStart;
    next(){
        isStart = true;
    }
};
```

and this map:

```
map<string, next> loc;
```

Only one "value" entry in the map has `isStart` set to true (rest are set to false in code I didn't post here). I need to iterate through the map and find out which one has `isStart` set to true (its corresponding `name`). I tried this:

```
string start;
map<string, next>::iterator it;
for(it=loc.begin(); it!=loc.end(); it++){
    if(*it.isStart){
        start = *it.name;
        break;
    }
}
```

and of course it didn't work. The iterator gives me a reference to the a particular map entry (the whole key value pair) but I can't figure out how to get to it's corresponding value entry. Am I iterating it wrong?

Comment: This ain't C my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have *two* problems with your code:

1. The first is that the dereference operator `*` have lower [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the selector operator `.`, so the compiler thinks you are doing `*(it.isStart)`.

   To solve this either use parentheses like `(*it).isStart` or the pointer-selector `->` like `it->isStart`.
2. The second problem is that the iterator, when dereferenced, gives you a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), which means you have to do e.g.

   ```
    if (it->second.isStart)
   ```

You might want to read e.g. [this `std::map` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Answer (score 0):

As this is about proper usage of iterators, I would recommend to use a const_iterator if you do not intend to modify anything, but just find the corresponding element and copy the key.

```
map<string, next>::const_iterator it;
```